# Run Python script using a hotkey when a specific program is active

Tags: python, windows, automation, hotkeys

Intended setup:

- Have `.py` script saved locally
- Run required program
- Use program normally until the need for the script arises
- Press hotkey that tells Windows to run the python script
- Close program when the script + my work is done
- Hotkey should not run the script anymore unless the program is opened again

Till now I've always manually run the script and quickly `Alt+Tab`'ing into the program before the script manages to start executing, but it's kind of a hassle. What's the general approach to do something like this?

OS: Windows

UPDATE: A method has been found. Though I'm keeping this thread active in case there are better options.

Comment: You can't do that easily/without external programs (Like AutoHotKey). You could create a python script that runs as a service and is always listening to the hotkey but only runs if it can find the program in the process list.

Comment: Hmm, I'll check out how to use AutoHotKey and windows services and then provide an update I guess

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoHotKey, e.g. setting Ctrl+F5 to run `script.py` when `Window Name` is active:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance

^f5::
{
    if WinActive("Window Name")
        Run "{your script path}\script.py"
}
```

Optional-1: If you want to run script in background (i.e. without console window appearing) rename your `script.py` to `script.pyw`

Optional-2: If you want to run your script with admin privileges without triggering UAC prompt (the admin yes/no prompt), [watch this for bypassing UAC prompt](https://youtu.be/Ai_l_L-8o-c) and [this for running any python scripts with task scheduler](https://youtu.be/4n2fC97MNac).

For the latter video, you will notice the script still runs in foreground (with console window). To prevent this, just type `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` when you are filling the 'Program/script:' field.